# I have 3 tables with relation. The first table have foreign id of another both tables. I want to know the exact query of fetching the data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model-view-controller

1. 3 MODELS-

1.1) PRODUCT MODEL -

```php
class Product extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'product_table(TableName)';

    public function banks()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Bank::class, 'bank_table', 'bank_id(ForeignKey)', 'id(PrimaryKey)');
    }

    public function product_category()
    {
       return $this->belongsToMany(ProductCategory::class, 'productcategory_table', 'productcategory_id(ForeignKey)', 'id(PrimaryKey)');
    }

}
```

1.2) BANK MODEL -

```php
class Bank extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'bank_table(TableName)';

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Product', 'id(PrimaryKey)', 'bank_id(ForeignKey)');
    }
}
```

1.3) PRODUCT CATEGORY MODEL -

```php
class ProductCatgory extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'mudra5_productcategory';
    
     public function mudra5_product()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Product');
    }
}
```

2. CONTROLLER CODE -

```php
public function cat()
{
    $alldata = Bank::with(['product'])->first();
    dd($alldata->product[0]->product_name);
}
```

3.ROUTE -

`Route::get('/borrower_profile', 'BorrowerAuth\statementController@cat')->name('mudra5_product');`

4. TABLES -

4.1) Product Table -

| id(int PK) | product_name(varchar(100)) | bank_id(ForeignKey) | category_id(ForeignKey) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | p1 |  |  |
| 2 | p2 |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |

4.2) Bank table-

| id(int PK) | bank_name | bank_logo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bank1 | img1 |
| 2 | Bank2 | img2 |
|  |  |  |

4.3) Product Category Table -

| id(int PK) | category_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | cat1 |
| 2 | cat2 |
|  |  |

OUTPUT Should be -

| id | category_name | bank_name | product_name |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | cat1 | bank1 bank2 bank3 | p1/p2/p3(bank1), p1/p2(bank2), p1/p2/p3(bank3) |  |
| 2 | cat2 | bank1 bank2 bank3 | p1/p2/p3(bank1), p1/p2/p3(bank2), p1/p2/p3(bank3) |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |

Comment: `belongsToMany` is for many to many relationships. Since each product only belongs to one bank or category you would need `belongsTo`

Answer (score 1):

if you put the foreign key then the relationship is HasMany-belongsTo (1-N) , for example if each product had one category then we put the foreign key of category_id in the product table since it can be only one .

in your case you have used belongsToMany not belongsTo thus a product can have many categories but you also put a foreign key in the table which dosnt go along with the belongsToMany .

you cannot put hasMany and belongsToMany together . choose one of them .

a belongsToMany is an eloquent relationship for N-N relationships and they require a pivot table no table can hold the other one _id so you make a picot table that has both ids and this table will handle the relationships queries traffic .

if you want to guard the relationships you presented than you need 5 tables (not 3)

Products
Categories
Banks
category_product
bank_product

#### Products

| id | product_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | p1 |
| 2 | p2 |

#### Categories

| id | category_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | c1 |
| 2 | c2 |

#### Banks

| id | bank_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | b1 |
| 2 | b2 |

#### category_product

| id | catrgory_id | product_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |

#### bank_product

| id | bank_id | product_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |

### Models

i you go by the docs you dont have to specify the table name of foreign key name laravel will discover it itself if you did the naming right ,

### Controller

first product :

```
    public function cat()
    {
        $firstBank= Bank::first();
        dd($firstBank->products()->first()->product_name);
    }
```

same output as your example ? : each category with its banks  and its products

```
    public function cat()
    {
        dd(Catgeory::with('banks' , 'products')->get());
    }
```

please check the official documentation of eloquent ORM [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)it explains lots of thing  with examples

check [this repo](https://github.com/HijenHEK/larablog-starter) for refrence where it has manyToMany relationship between Tags & Posts